# Not able to fix the error I get while writing code for analyzing "California Housing" data set from O'Reilly book

Tags: python, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, data-science

while executing code:(from book page 69 of "Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn, Keras, and TensorFlow: Concepts, Tools, and Techniques to Build Intelligent Systems
Book by Aurelien Geron")

```
housing_cat_encoded = ordinal_encoder.fit_transform(housing_cat)

housing_cat_encoded[:10]
```

I get error:-

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=['<1H OCEAN' '<1H OCEAN' 'NEAR OCEAN' ... 'INLAND' '<1H OCEAN' 'NEAR BAY'].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

How do I fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case the error describes the issue and a way to solve it. The function `.fit_transform()` is expecting a 2D array, not a 1D one. A way of achieving this, is using `.reshape()`. Since we are passing a single column (feature) then we should use `-1,1`.

```
housing_cat_encoded = ordinal_encoder.fit_transform(housing_cat.reshape(-1,1))
```

If `housing_cat` is a pandas series, then you might have to use:

```
housing_cat_encoded = ordinal_encoder.fit_transform(housing_cat.values.reshape(-1,1))
```

Comment: It worked with code you told for pandas series. Thank You.